# How to omit the space after the comma when scanning comma separated strings in C

Tags: c, string

When inputting strings which are separated by a comma the second string will print with space on the beginning. I need to scan and print comma separated string without whitespace in the beginning. This is my current code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[30];
    char r[30];
  
    scanf("%[^,],%[^\n]",s,r);
    
      printf("%s\n",s);
      printf("%s",r);

  
    return 0;
}
```

The output when   hello world, o wor   is the input is

```
hello world
 o wor
```

It should be

```
hello world 
o wor
```

Comment: There are many ways to *trim* or *strip* leading or trailing white-space in strings, if you search a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a whitespace before `%[]` will exclude it.

```c
scanf("%[^,], %[^\n]",s,r);
```